# MongoDB: Assertion 15934 Error

Tags: mongodb, heroku

I am using Heroku as my deployment and trying to dump my local MongoDB then mongorestore it but I get an error that simply I can't get:

```
assertion: 15934 JSON object size didn't match file size
```

I searched everything and the closest thing I found was the mongodb source code in github.

Does anyone know why this error would happen?

Comment: I suggest you ask in MongoDB's own forum. Meanwhile try using textual format import/export using mongoimport/mongoexport. mongodump/mongorestore uses the binary BSON format.

Answer (score 0):

The 15934 assertion error would indicate that the file size does not match the actual size of the JSON objects that make up that file.  This could come about from editing of the file before trying to restore it - if you have manually removed fields from the file you will see this error for example.

One thing you should be aware of if you are using `mongoexport`/`mongoimport` is that it will not take care of the indexes for you.  This means that you would need to create the indexes on your own either before or after the import is completed.  Creating them before could cause the import to take a lot longer to run.